# How do I do I convert Arabic (Unicode encoded) to byte hex representation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, encoding

I am trying to use http request to calling a website using iPhone; by developing a little application in Objective-C, however I am having problems passing Arabic characters! as I need to use unicode in hex like ([Arabic characters in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_characters_in_Unicode) ?

I have done this before developing a website using PHP using the below function:

```
/**
* Converts a string to USC-2 encoding if neccessary.
*/

function string_unicode($string) 
{
    if (function_exists('iconv')) 
    {  
      $latin = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $string);

        if (strcmp($latin, $string)) 
         {
            $arr = unpack('H*hex', @iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE', $string));
              return strtoupper($arr['hex']) .'&unicode=1';  
         }
     }

    return FALSE;
 }
```

BUT I am struggling to achieve the same in Objective-C, please help!! Thanks

Comment: How are you passing Arabic characters? In the URL? In the request body? What problem do you have specifically?

Comment: The most important I need to encode them in the  unicode hex format Like (0628 for ب) then I need to escape them maybe by using the add escape percent, my problem is how to do what the php code above does i.e cheack the text if it was Latin then do nothing otherwise convert the Arabic chars into this hex format ? Many thanks

Comment: There are other, standardized ways to send Unicode over HTTP like URL escape codes or JSON encoding, can't you use them? You can even send raw Unicode encoded text if the server is expecting it. Otherwise you should change your question and title to explicitly say "how do I convert Unicode encoded text to byte hex representation"?

Comment: I am looking for an equivalent to the above PHP code in Objective-C? Any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Finally it was rather very simple solution by using formatting!!

```
-(NSString *)getUniCode:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSString *theStringToReturn  = nil;


    NSMutableString *theEncodedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

    for (NSInteger theCharIndex=0; theCharIndex< [message length]; theCharIndex++) {

        [theEncodedString appendFormat: @"%04x", [message characterAtIndex: theCharIndex]];

    }

    theStringToReturn = [NSString stringWithString:theEncodedString];

    return theStringToReturn;
}
```

I hope this will help others.